# Is there a way to select multiple values in an IF statement in Calculated Field?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm creating a calculated field where I'm trying to do an if then statement based on the selection from a filter.  The user has 3 choices...for Example....They can choose Null and Infection_Type_A, Null and Infection_Type_B, Null and Infection_Type_A and Infection_Type_B.  But when I try to combine the two choices for example Null and Infection_Type_A it only reads one of them instead of both.

Answer (score 1):

in such scenarios its recommended to use the SWITCH CASE statements

```
If [Business Unit] is "Business Unit 1" AND [Work Area] is "Work Area 1" THEN

CASE [Current Reviewer]

WHEN "Person 1" THEN 1

WHEN "Person 2" THEN 2

WHEN "Person 3" THEN 3

ELSE 100 END
```

you can refer to this example:
https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C65QdSAJ/case-statement-with-multiple-conditions

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help!  I read it over....so, is this how it works?........  IF [Infection Field] is null and [Infection Field]  = 'Infection_Type_A' then '1.024'  elseif [Infection Field] is null and [Infection Field]  = 'Infection_Type_B' then '1.46  END

Comment: yes it works, but it'd be difficult to manage your code after sometime, so best to plan ahead

Comment: Appreciate you.....curious as to why it would be difficult to manage?